# WSO2 ESB ServiceNow connector

Tags: caching, servicenow, wso2-esb

Hi I am trying to get records from incident table from a serviceNow instance using the ServiceNow connector from ESB. I am able to get back the filtered query records from incident table using the respond mediator.Can anybody tell me the way to cache these records in a detailed way?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use cache mediator to cache the response message. you can refer more at [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Cache+Mediator).

Comment: Yes , but if we use respond mediator in the in-sequence we cannot use cache mediator as cache mediator's finder component needs to be in the In-sequence and the collector component needs to be in out-sequence.
Moreover we cannot use send mediator if we are using the serviceNow connector as it handles the endpoint internally.Please advise on how should I proceed

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the cache mediator. You don't necessarily need to have the configuration in in-sequence and out-sequence respectively. Please try the following.

```
<cache timeout="20" scope="per-host" collector="false" hashGenerator="org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.DOMHASHGenerator">
     <implementation type="memory" maxSize="100"/>
</cache>
```

This is where the request's hash is generated to store in the cache. If you have this segment at the request which you need to cache, that would suffice.

```
<cache scope="per-host" collector="true"/>
```

This where the response is being cached. You can add this right after the ServiceNow call. If the request matches the hash when it reaches the first configuration it will respond to the client from the cache this way.

Comment: Hi maheeka,
The error log shows CacheMediator Request messages cannot be handled in a collector cache.